# Dynamic file import in Angular Project

Tags: angularjs, typescript, environment-variables

I'm building an hybrid angular app. The AngularJs Code has three different file for constants based on environment, created in this way

```
angular.module(...).constants(...).
```

I have a file called index.ts where i import the files of my project.

index.ts

```
 import "./js/constants";
 import "./js/constants_svil";
 import "./js/constants_stage";
 import "./js/constants_dev";
 import "./js/angular-multi-select";
 import "./js/angular-indexed-db";
 import "./js/calendar";
 import "./js/abmoment.min";
 import "./js/acmoment-timezone-with-data";
 import "./js/amoment-timezone-utils";
 import "./js/fullcalendar";
 import "./js/gcal";
 import "./js/lang-all";
```

Is there a way to dynamically load this constants file based on environment? I saw there is a dynamic import used to load modules implemented in Typescript 2.4. Could it work? I need this file only for side effects, they don't have an export statement inside.

Edit: Now i'm using typescript 3.9

Answer (score 0):

you can define different files for different build configurations in the `angular.json`:

example:

```
  "production": {
    "fileReplacements": [
      {
        "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
        "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    ],
    ...
```

see: https://angular.io/guide/build

Comment: i have one file with default constants, and three different files based on environment. In the angularjs project, this three file would have been loaded conditionally. I was hoping to find a method to do so even in Angular